# data not fetching from a view

Tags: sql, oracle

When we are running below code we are not getting records , the same code returned some records previously.

I tried changing the code by modifying some part in DATE conditions.

```
select columns
from VIEW
WHERE TRUNC(END_TIME) BETWEEN TO_DATE(date) AND TO_DATE(date)
  and outcome_category='<<value>>'
```

The View should return all records which satisfy the between clause condition.

Comment: Please check if the data is  present for the given date range.

Comment: SELECT also TRUNC(END_TIME) and TO_DATE(date), and remove that condition from the WHERE clause. Does the returned result make any indications?

Comment: @jarlh can you please reply the your suggested code once.

Comment: My comment wasn't intended to be a solution, just a way for you to verify your data!

Comment: make sure session parameters like org_id have been set...

Comment: supply data from your table, THEN we can help you

Comment: supply also the view code as it might be filtering data